# Problem with Indic numerals (mashriq form) after bidi & xetex update

Tags: xetex, bidi

After some update (bidi,latex,xetex,...) I'm facing problem in numbers with . or - which is not happening previously, numbering direction is correct with maghrib form 0,1,2,...,9 but with mashriq form ٠,١,٢,٣,٤,٥,٦,٧,٨,٩ direction of numbering do not change with command (\setlatin - \setnonlatin)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\setRTL
\setnonlatin

\section{text}
\subsection{text text}
\subsection{text text}

1.23 % change direction with \setnonlatin - \setlatin 

١.٢٣ <-- % do not change direction with \setnonlatin - \setlatin


\hrulefill

\setlatin

1.23

١.٢٣

\end{document}
```

[image]

**From log file**

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)
>   (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.10.16)  3 NOV 2019
>
> Package: bidi 2019/10/19 v35.10 Bidirectional typesetting in plain TeX
>   and LaTeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as posted contains Unicode 0661, 0662, 0663. This is *Arabic-Indic Digit One* and *Two* and *Three*. However, `bidi` checks for 06F1 to 06F9, which is *Extended Arabic-Indic Digit* one to nine. So change those in the source and it works as expected.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\setRTL
\setnonlatin

\section{text}
\subsection{text text}
\subsection{text text}
1.23\par % change direction with \setnonlatin - \setlatin 
١.٢٣ <-- \par % Arabic Indic Digits do not change direction with \setnonlatin - \setlatin
۱.۲۳ \par % Extended Arabic-Indic Digits
\hrulefill

\setlatin
1.23 \par
١.٢٣ \par
۱.۲۳ \par

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Alternatively, you can add the non-extended Arabic-Indic digits to the digits charclass:

```
\usepackage{bidi}
\makeatletter
\bidi@digits=1633 \loop \XeTeXcharclass \bidi@digits \bidi@digits@charclass \ifnum\bidi@digits<1641 \advance\bidi@digits \@ne \repeat
\makeatother
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think this needs to be added to `bidi`.